# Query in SQL Server to combine tables

Tags: sql-server

I need a query in SQL Server to combine tables like these:

**TBL1**

```
ID   TITLE1
-----------
1    t1
2    t2
3    t3
```

**TBL2**

```
ID   TITLE2
------------
100    c1
200    c2
```

Now I need tbl3 as a result:

**TBL3**

```
col1  col2
-----------
t1    c1
t1    c2
t2    c1
t2    c2
t3    c1
t3    c2
```

How can I get `tbl3` without any key between these 2 tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a cross join:

```
SELECT
    t1.TITLE1 AS col1,
    t2.TITLE2 AS col2
FROM TBL1 t1
CROSS JOIN TBL2 t2
ORDER BY
    t1.TITLE1,
    t2.TITLE2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [TITLE1] varchar(2)) 
INSERT INTO #Table1 
VALUES
    (1, 't1'),
    (2, 't2'),
    (3, 't3')

CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([ID] int, [TITLE2] varchar(2))


INSERT INTO #Table2
   VALUES
    (100, 'c1'),
    (200, 'c2')

SELECT Title1 as col1, Title2 as col2
FROM #Table1
CROSS JOIN #Table2 order by Title1 

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```

Here is the output shown below.

```
col1    col2
t1      c1
t1      c2
t2      c2
t2      c1
t3      c1
t3      c2
```

Answer (score 0):

CROSS JOIN will work for your case.

That is result-set contains the number of rows in the first table, multiplied by the number of rows in second table when there is no WHERE clause.

/**********************************/

SELECT

```
a.TITLE1 AS col1,
b.TITLE2 AS col2
```

FROM

```
      TBL1 a
```

CROSS JOIN

```
      TBL2 b
```

/**********************************/